# How to prove that a function has no absolute extrema?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For the function $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-2xy$, 
I know how to use the Extreme Value Theorem to calculate, also I can intuitively get the answer from the graph. But, is there an easy way to prove this function has no absolute maximum/minimum.
Thanks.

Comment: Show that $f(x,0)$ is unbounded, and show that implies that no global extrema exist.

Comment: I got it. thanks for pointing me out

Comment: @dxiv: As the OP got his problem solved, it is recommended to post your comment as an answer (I can do it for you if you wish), so that the answer is marked "answered".

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I encourage the OP to fill-in the missing blanks and post a [self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The fast and easy way is to use the Second-Partials Test. Hope this helps

[image]